# How do I remove the quotation marks from each element of a list containing dates that I have import from excel?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, date-and-time, finance

I've been stuck in this problem for 1 week. I just want to make a graph (Log-Return vs time (in year, month, day)).

The code is:

```
datanikkei = Import["C:\\Users\\Rodrigo\\Desktop\\Nikkei.csv"] #Here I import the data from excel
close = datanikkei[[All, 5]]; #take the close price column
close = Delete[close, 1]; #Delete Title
ret = Differences[Log[close]*100.0] #calculate the returns

date = datanikkei[[All, 1]]; #Take the dates column
date = Delete[date, {{1}, {2}}]; #Delete title and first date of the list
date = Partition[date, 1]
list = Riffle[date, ret]
list = Partition[list, 2]
DateListPlot[list]
```

I get this:

```
{{{"1984,1,5"}, 0.201268}, {{"1984,1,6"}, 
  0.140647}, {{"1984,1,7"}, -0.0702988}, {{"1984,1,8"}, 
  0.620933}, {{"1984,1,9"}, 0.567476}, {{"1984,1,10"}, 
  0.307281}, {{"1984,1,11"}, 0.464084}, {{"1984,1,12"}...
```

The different functions that I had used (like DateListPlot) to plot the returns vs the dates gave an error. But if I errase the quotation marks, it works. The error is:

> DateListPlot::dtvals: "Unable to automatically determine horizontal
>   coordinates for the given data and DataRange. !(*ButtonBox[\">>\",
>   Appearance->{Automatic, None}, BaseStyle->\"Link\",
>   ButtonData:>\"paclet:ref/DateListPlot\",
>   ButtonNote->\"DateListPlot::dtvals\"])"

Please, help me
Rodrigo

Comment: I've partially formatted your question but note that comments in Mathematica are written like: `(* #Delete title and first date of the list *)`

Comment: Notwithstanding the fix in the answer below, your output is unusual `{"1984,1,5"}`. Normally dates are converted to date lists when imported from CSV or Excel so this problem shouldn't arise (??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mydata = {{{"1984,1,5"}, 0.201268}, {{"1984,1,6"}, 0.140647}, 
         {{"1984,1,7"}, -0.0702988}, {{"1984,1,8"}, 0.620933}, 
         {{"1984,1,9"}, 0.567476}, {{"1984,1,10"}, 0.307281}, 
         {{"1984,1,11"}, 0.464084}};

fixedData = ToExpression /@ ({StringSplit[#[[1]][[1]], ","], #[[2]]} & /@ mydata)

DateListPlot[fixedData]
```

[image]

The trick was splitting the string using the criterion of a comma, then converting each individual string numeral into an integer via `ToExpression`.

Comment: +1 -- `FromDigits` is a bit safer than `ToExpression` however as it is less general, avoiding possibly unwanted code execution.

Comment: Ohh... a subtlety.  Yes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another formulation:

```
list = {{{"1984,1,5"}, 0.201268},
        {{"1984,1,6"}, 0.140647},
        {{"1984,1,7"}, -0.0702988},
        {{"1984,1,8"}, 0.620933},
        {{"1984,1,9"}, 0.567476},
        {{"1984,1,10"}, 0.307281},
        {{"1984,1,11"}, 0.464084}};

list /. {s_String} :> ImportString[s, "CSV"][[1]]
```

> ```
> {{{1984, 1, 5}, 0.201268}, {{1984, 1, 6}, 0.140647},
>  {{1984, 1, 7}, -0.0702988}, {{1984, 1, 8}, 0.620933},
>  {{1984, 1, 9}, 0.567476}, {{1984, 1, 10}, 0.307281},
>  {{1984, 1, 11}, 0.464084}}
> ```

Comment: @MathLind It is the result of a code block inside a quote block.  Each line is started with `>` followed by five spaces.  You can select the output and use the buttons in the editor toolbar.  Not everyone thinks it's nice, but it works for me.