# Removing quotes from fields after import of table

Tags: import, csv-format

I would like to remove quotes around fields when importing a `csv` table. It should be simple, but I cannot find any answer.

My data is in the format `{{r, t}, f[r, t]}` and it is a table of a couple of thousand fields.

I have experimented with exporting as `.data` with option `"Table"` and then importing as `"TSV"`, and with `.csv` and playing with `"TextDelimiter"` and `"FieldSeparator"`. Even if the `.csv` file has no quotes around fields, they get it upon import.

I need to do an interpolation of the data and it does not work with the quotes that are applied.

Any comments on the proper procedure would be appreciated, i.e., if `csv` is not the most optimal way of exporting etc.

EDIT: While composing this post I discovered the `.wdx` format which works out of the box, but I am still interested in knowing what I was doing wrong about the `.csv`.

Comment: `ToExpression@Import[]`?

Comment: See [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72727/how-do-i-remove-the-quotation-marks-from-each-element-of-a-list-containing-dates)

Comment: Thanks for the link and the `ToExpression[]` / `ToExpression@`. I had already found the link but couldn't understand the syntax, which did not work out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer, as given in comments by Feyre and Gavy, the way to avoid the double quotations is to import in the following way

```
importedTable = ToExpression[Import["file.csv"]]
```

or

```
importedTable = ToExpression@Import["file.csv"]
```

or to use another format, as I edited

```
Export["file.wdx"]
importedTable = Import["file.wdx"]
```